# How to search for an integer within a nested class with the binary_search STL function?

Tags: c++, stl, binary-search

How to search for an integer within a nested class with the `binary_search` STL function? Is it possible to do a binary search on the vector `vITems` to search for the product class ID? Currently, I have to populate a `std::vector<Product> vProd` array inside the `Order` class to use the `binary_search` function.

I did a lot of research on the subject, but I was unsuccessful in solving the problem.

```
 #include <iostream>
    #include <algorithm>
    #include <vector>

    class Product {
    public:

        int Id;
        std::string Name;

        Product(int idProd, const std::string &nameProd) : Id(idProd), Name(nameProd) {}
        Product(int idProd) : Id(idProd)  {} // Required for lambda function to work on binary_search function
    };

    class Item {
    public:

        Product Prod;
        int Number;

        Item(Product &prod, int numProd) : Prod(prod), Number(numProd) {}
    };

    class Order{
    private:
        std::vector<Item> vItems;

    public:

        bool consultProd(int idProd) const {
            std::vector<Product> vProd;
            size_t total = vItems.size();

            for(size_t i = 0; i < total; i++)
                vProd.push_back(vItems[i].Prod);


            bool yesId = binary_search( vProd.begin(), vProd.end(), idProd,
                                   []( const Product &p1, const Product &p2)
                                    {
                                        return p1.Id < p2.Id;
                                    } );

            return yesId;
        }


        void setItem(Item &it){
            vItems.push_back(it);
        }

    };


    int main()
    {
        //----------------------------------------------------------------
        Product p1(1, "aaa"), p2(2, "bbb"), p3(3, "ccc"), p4(4, "ddd");

        Item it1(p1, 1), it2(p2, 3), it3(p3, 3), it4(p4, 7);

        Order ord;

        ord.setItem(it1);
        ord.setItem(it2);
        ord.setItem(it3);
        ord.setItem(it4);
        //----------------------------------------------------------------

        if( !ord.consultProd(2) )
            ord.setItem(it2);
        else
          std::cout << "Warning: Product already included in the order.\n";

        system("pause");


        return 0;
}
```

Comment: It's unclear what the problem is. You are already using binary_search.

Comment: Your provided code works. you build implicitly a `Product` from integer though.

Comment: @eerorika Yes, but I need to fill in a product vector in order to get the Product ID. Would it be possible to get this product ID from the Items vector?

Comment: Unclear what you want... Get rid of `Product(int idProd)`?

Comment: @Jarod42 Get rid of having to create a product vector to do a search.I wonder if it is possible to search the product ID within ITEMs vector.

Comment: @DiegoHilário Have you thought this through?  If you're going to have a sorted vector, you should be utilizing `std::lower_bound` and/or `std::upper_bound` when inserting an item in the vector that's supposed to be sorted.   Your current program uses a toy number of items, but what if there are 100 items, and you want to insert another item and keep the list sorted?

Comment: @DiegoHilário why not pass (iterators to) the item vector into the binary search instead?

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Could you please explain your idea in code? I couldn't understand, sorry, I'm starting in C ++ programming.

Comment: If you want to keep a sorted list, when you insert an item, you need to know where to insert the item so that the list is still sorted.  One way is to just place the item anywhere, and then let `std::sort` sort the list again.  The problem with that it is a lot of work to sort an entire list just to ensure that the newly inserted item is in the right position.  Instead of that, there are functions `std::lower_bound` and `std::upper_bound` that will give you the position of where to place the item, and you just place the item at that position, all without having to do a full `std::sort`.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie, I now understand your explanation. Using upper or lowe_bound I would avoid using the Sort function, because these functions already make the vector sorted. Now, for teaching purposes, could you tell me how you could use a classification like this in my code: sort(vItems.begin(), vItems.end(), [](const Item& it1, const Item& it2){ return it1.Prod.Id  < it2.Prod.Id; });

Answer (score 1):

With helper:

```
template<class... Ts> struct overloaded : Ts... { using Ts::operator()...; };
template<class... Ts> overloaded(Ts...) -> overloaded<Ts...>;
```

You might do with custom comparer:

```
bool consultProd(int idProd) const {
    return binary_search(
        vItems.begin(),
        vItems.end(),
        idProd,
        overloaded{[](int id, const Item& item) { return id < item.Prod.Id; },
                   [](const Item& item, int id) { return item.Prod.Id < id; }
                  });
}
```

[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/de56b6b845fca219)

Comment: Great solution. I need to study more about templates. They can do magnificent things from what I see. Thank you, friend.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`std::lower_bound`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/lower_bound):

```
const auto item_it = std::lower_bound(vItems.begin(), vItems.end(), idProd,
    [](const Item& item, int id) { return item.Prod.Id < id; });

const bool yesId = (item_it != vItems.end() && item_it->Prod.Id == idProd);
return yesId;
```

Note that `[vItems.begin(), vItems.end())` should represent a valid range of items sorted by `Prod.Id` or at least partitioned with respect to `Prod.Id < idProd`. If this condition is not fulfilled, the behaviour of `std::lower_bound` is undefined.

---

> What is the correct way to do this ordering?

If the range is not sorted, the correct way is to use [`std::find_if`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/find):

```
const auto item_it = std::find_if(vItems.begin(), vItems.end(), 
    [idProd](const Item& item) { return item.Prod.Id == idProd; });

const bool yesId = (item_it != vItems.end());
```

Sorting before each binary search doesn't make sense: binary search takes `O(log n)` time, but sorting takes `O(n log n)` time. This is worse than linear time complexity `O(n)` provided by `std::find_if`.

Comment: Magnificent solution. Thank you so much, friend.

Comment: What is the correct way to do this ordination? Tried as follows, but to no avail.

 
[code] sort (vItems.begin(), vItems.end(), [](const Item& it1, const Item& it2){ return it1.Prod.Id  < it2.Prod.Id; }); [\code]

Comment: @DiegoHilário -- You can still keep the list sorted if you insert your items in the correct sort position.  My comment in the main section already stated to use `std::lower_bound` and `std::upper_bound` to accomplish this.  By doing this, you spare yourself from calling `std::sort` each time.

Comment: Splendid explanation. It really convinced me that in this case a linear ordering is the correct. Now, taking the performace question out of context, how would I do a proper binary order in the context of my code? I tried to create a constructor [code] Item (Product & prod): Prod (prod) {} [\ code] and use the function [code] sort (vItems.begin (), vItems.end (), [] (const Item & it1 , const Item & it2) {return it1.Prod.Id <it2.Prod.Id;}); [code], but got an error: "error: passing 'const Item' as 'this' argument discards qualifiers [-fpermissive] | "

Comment: @Evg Thank you so much, friend. I am learning a lot from you all.

Comment: @DiegoHilário, the problem is that `consultProd()` has `const` specifier, so you can't modify `vItems` inside it. Remove `const`, and it will work.

Comment: @Evg Thank you so much, friend. Problem solved and one more learning.